# Finding the smallest value in an array

Tags: c++

So I'm having some trouble with something. I have to create a function that will find the smallest number in an array. I know of one way to do it, using an overkill amount of if/else if, which won't do any good if the array size changes. I know using a for loop should do the trick but I can't figure out how to write it. Any push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

```html
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int findLowest(int[]);

int main()
{
    int AR[5] = {4, 87, 1, -3, 78};
    cout << findLowest(AR);

    return 0;
}

int findLowest(int AR[])
{

     return lowest;
}
```

Comment: Unless you want/need to do this on your own, perhaps look up `std::min_element`.

Comment: "won't do any good if the array size changes" Does it change while you are performing the task? If not, just store temp element and check against it.

Answer (score 3):

If you can change the function signature and include a header file that specifies general limits, you could do the following, which reads through the array in one pass:

```
#include <climits>
...

/* assumes AR_size > 0 */
int findLowest(int AR[], int AR_size)
{
     int lowest = INT_MAX;
     for (i = 0; i < AR_size; ++i) {
         lowest = (AR[i] < lowest) ? AR[i] : lowest;
     }
     return lowest;
}
```

Comment: `lowest = (AR[i] < lowest) ? AR[i] : lowest;` is clean but inefficient as it causes an assignment to itself. The optimizer may remove this, but `if (AR[i] < lowest) lowest = AR[i];` should be faster.

Comment: I like ternary statements for some reason. More readable, maybe. Point taken but the performance hit will likely be very minimal.

Comment: Is there more efficient way then this one without using if(ar[i] > lower)?

Comment: @AlexReynolds I also like ternary statements and use them quite often, but I do embedded development and if this function was used a lot the single assembly call could turn out to be a big deal. If living in the desktop world than no need to worry about the little stuff.

Comment: @CroCo You need to initialize the variable to a maximum value so that the first index will always be less. If you didn't have to worry about an empty array you could rewrite to initialize the variable to the first array element and start the for loop with `i=1` which would be more efficient.

Comment: @LINEMAN78, initialize it with the first element in the array and start comparing. Isn't it?

Comment: @CroCo You can't make the assumption that there is a first element. What if someone passes in an empty array?

Comment: @LINEMAN78, of course there must be check for that but my point is that if the array have numbers greater than `INT_MAX`, then this function will return `INT_MAX`.

Comment: @CroCo There can be no number greater than `INT_MAX` stored into an int. The value of `INT_MAX` is compiler dependent, however assuming your compiler defines int as a 32 bit number, then `INT_MAX` is 2^31 (since int is signed). The whole point is to initialize it to the largest possible number it can be. `INT_MAX` is defined in limits.h, look at the documentation.

Comment: @LINEMAN78, practically speaking yes "There can be no number greater than `INT_MAX` stored into an int" but theoretically  speaking it sounds odd to assume it as a number in the array while it is not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92788/discussion-between-lineman78-and-croco).

Comment: Lineman, your points about embedded design are good and correct. I work with desktops all the time so I forget that world exists.

Comment: IMO it's up to the caller in this context to make sure their array has at least one element in it, before calling `findLowest`. There is no sensible return value in the case of a null pointer.

Answer (score 3):

```
template<size_t N>
int findLowest(int (&ar)[N])
{
    return *std::min_element(std::begin(ar), std::end(ar));
}
```

Note the usage of a template to make sure we get the size information from the caller.

Comment: Definitely more C++-ic

Answer (score 0):

Instead of defining your own function to find the smallest number in your array, why do you not use the standard `std::min_element` function to do it for you? Create a `std::vector` object from the array, and let the min_element function do the job for you.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#define ARRAY_SIZE 5

int main ( int argc, char **argv )
{
        int ar [ ARRAY_SIZE ] = {4, 87, 1, -3, 78};

        std::vector<int> arVector ( ar, ar + ARRAY_SIZE );

        std::cout << *std::min_element ( arVector.begin ( ), arVector.end ( )) << std::endl;

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Output:

```
-3
```

Comment: mega overkill. The standard library already has a `min_element` function.

Comment: Sorting to find a minimum (or maximum) value is relatively expensive and unnecessary when you can find bounds in linear time (one pass).

Comment: My bad, I was a little quick to read the question. Thought he wanted a sorting function. I have corrected it now.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;

int findLowest(int ar[], const int& SIZE)
{
    assert(("Error: the size of the array is zero. Make sure that ", SIZE > 0));

    int lowest = ar[0];

    for(int i=0; i<SIZE;i++)
    {
        if(lowest > ar[i])
            lowest = ar[i];
    }
    return lowest;
}

int main()
{
    const int SIZE(5);
    int AR[5] = {11, 12, 10, 14, 15};
    cout << findLowest(AR,SIZE);

    return 0;
}
```